# How to connect to web site in docker container outside the host [Windows server] nginx

Tags: angular, containers

my web site is inside a docker container and work in server by url localhost:9902.
my webserver is nginx and windows server
but when I request to http://myip:80 from outside server don't work it
My website with nginx is inside a docker container

```
worker_processes auto;      
events {
  worker_connections 512;    
}
http {
  server {
    listen *:80;            
    server_name "";         
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    location / {
      proxy_pass                http://localhost:9902/;
      proxy_redirect            off;
      proxy_set_header          Host  $host;
      proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Proto  http;
      proxy_buffer_size         128k;
      proxy_buffers             8 128k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Nginx configuration seems correct and if you can access it in your LAN, this can only be a networking problem.

### There are a few things that need to be verified:

1. Do your Docker container has the port 80 bound to the outside? [(doc here)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)
2. If "outside" is Internet, use HTTP://**your-public-ip**:80
3. Create a NAT rule to redirect all incoming traffic from your router on the port 80 to your server IP on the port 80 too. Check your router's user manual.

I never tried to access my docker containers from the Internet, but with a NAT rule in your router, it should work.

Hopes it helps!